# Generate guid on Swagger-UI with OpenAPI Document

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, .net-8.0

I have an OpenAPI document and I want to generate random guid's on Swagger-UI. Currently, it's generating a 'string' value without the format applied.

```json
{
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "guid"
    }
}
```

Here's my code:

```cs
    app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
    {
        settings.DocumentPath = $"/{pathBase}/api/specification.json";
    });
    
    app.UseOpenApi();
 

       services.AddOpenApiDocument((configure, sp) =>
        {

        var config = sp.CreateScope().ServiceProvider
        .GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        configure.PostProcess = d =>
        {
            d.Servers.Add(new NSwag.OpenApiServer { Url = $"/{config["SwaggerBasePath"]}" });
            d.Servers.Add(new NSwag.OpenApiServer { Url = $"/" });
        };
        // Add the fluent validations schema processor
        var fluentValidationSchemaProcessor =
            sp.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FluentValidationSchemaProcessor>();

        configure.SchemaSettings.SchemaProcessors.Add(fluentValidationSchemaProcessor);
        configure.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT"));

    });
```

How can I generate random guid's each time?

Answer (score 0):

There is no format defined for `guid`.

Use `uuid`

```json
    {
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "uuid"
      }
    }
```

Comment: what changes to make in code?

Comment: the code you mentioned there doesn't indicate where you defined the schema